# How to draw a box by X and Y coordinates with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to draw a box by X and Y coordinates. But I can't find a sample. I want to draw only clicked area nearly. The example in this picture is wrong. I just want to mark the clicked area.

**It's wrong**

[image: Wrong]

**It must be like this**

This is my snippet:

[image]

```js
$('[class^="col"]').on("click", function(e) {
  //alert("X: " + e.pageX + " Y: " + e.pageY + " Data: " + $(this).data('area'))
    $(this).position().top = e.pageX
    $(this).position().left = e.pageY
    $(this).css("border", "5px solid #00ff")
 })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" data-area="1">
   <table class="table front-table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Content</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class="ID">1</td>
      <td class="Title">Test Title</td>
      <td class="Content">Test Content</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <hr />
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" data-area="2">
   test
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This snipped is not working correctly. How can I do it?

**Update for understandable**

I just want to draw a box around the clicked area.

Comment: This is not clear at all. Not clear what *"select area"* means, or what that picture is supposed to show us or what *"is not working properly"* means exactly

Comment: @charlietfl I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean this whole issue is not understandable

Comment: @charlietfl I just want to draw a box around the clicked area.

Comment: Also no idea why you set `$(this).position().top = e.pageX`. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Define "draw a box"

Comment: This is my mistake and is not important.

Comment: Not going to go to chat...it is up to you to clearly define in the question exactly what it is you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. I will try. It complex for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the original element that is being clicked with `e.target`:

```
$(e.target).css("border", "5px solid #00ff")
```